# How to determine why a check_constraint is failing?

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

My application uses SQL Server 2017 and I am having an issue running a simple `UPDATE` to a table.

I get the following SQL exception:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__AGENTS__AGENT_ST__32AB8735"

I am trying to determine what the actual check is, because I do not recall setting one up for the column in question.

I have tried running the following query but the `definition` column is `null`:

```
SELECT
    name,
    type_desc,
    definition
FROM 
    sys.check_constraints;
```

The column is a simple `VARCHAR(10)` and the SQL statement causing the error is this:

```
UPDATE AGENTS
SET AGENT_STATUS = 'INACTIVE';
```

How do I determine what the check is actually looking for and why it is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried running the following query but the definition column is
>   null:
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     name,
>     type_desc,
>     definition
> FROM 
>     sys.check_constraints;
> ```

Yor code is correct and it actually retrieves `check constraint` definition, but if you see `NULL` instead of it this means that you have not sufficient `permissions` to see `check constraint definition`.

You can see what permissions you have on this table using this code:

```
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions ('your_table_schema.your_table_name', 'object');
```

You cannot see `check constraint` definition unless you have `VIEW DEFINITION` on the object.